# The auxiliary verb "will" for the pronoun "we" and "I" isn't correct?

Tags: usage, auxiliary-verbs

I was told in the past by my teacher that the auxiliary verb "will" for the pronoun "we" and "I" isn't correct and it dhould be "shall" in the cases (i.g. "we shall be there" rather than "we will be there". But since normally I don't notice that people use "shall" I thought it is anarchonistic and it reflects the past. But yesterday I found this article ([What’s the difference between ‘will’ and ‘shall’?](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/09/will-versus-shall/)) of Oxford dictionary which still claims that the correct one is shall.

Maybe some native speakers from different English speaking countries can tell us the reality about this issue.

Comment: This might be a regional, I think. When I use 'shall' here in Texas, I often get smiled at and even told I am being a snob. I was brought up in Canada by British parents, and 'shall' was simply part of everyday speech. Here  'I will', and  'we will' are both widely used.

Comment: You need to read that article more carefully: what it says is that "die-hard grammatical sticklers" follow this rule; that "not all varieties of British English" follow this distinction; that "will and shall are equally acceptable"; and (quoting Fowler) that "there is not much doubt that will will win, and shall shall lose, in the end."

Comment: Since you can use either word, I will add that to me (AmE) "*shall*" sounds more assertively declarative, whereas "*will*" could be a simple mention of a future happening.  That is, "*shall*" sounds more firm than will*".

Comment: @StewC Indeed, this is the predominant use of *shall* in AmE: in legal and bureaucratic texts to indicate that the complement is obligatory.

Comment: From the Ten Commandments: "Thou **shall** not..." which is understood to mean "You **will not**..."